# Reduce number in text box by one for each button tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm relatively new to Objective-C so this might be really simple to do: I have a text box in my application that displays an ammo count, so each time the user taps a fire button the number in the text box will go down by one (12 > 11 > 10, etc) to 0. I have tried using for and if statements, but they are not working (I may have used incorrect syntax). This is what I'm using right now, but obviously I need the

```
- (IBAction)fire {

    [ammoField setText:@"11"];

}

- (IBAction)reload {

    [ammoField setText: @"12"];

}
```

Comment: `int` count; in your `.h` file, in `viewDidLoad` count = something, do count --  in your action, use `stringWithFormat` to show count value in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to convert the text to a number, decrement that and the reset the text, i.e. replace the code in the fire method with:

```
NSInteger ammoCount = [ammoField.text integerValue];
ammoCount--;
ammoField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ammoCount];
```

But don't do this, it will make baby Steve Jobs cry.

A better way would be to add a new variable to the class of type `UIInteger` that tracks the the number of bullets, i.e.:

```
// in interface
NSInteger _ammoCount;

...

// in implementation

- (IBAction)fire {
    _ammoCount--;
    if (_ammoCount <= 0) {
        _ammoCount = 0;
        fireButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    [ammoField setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _ammoCount]];
}

- (IBAction)reload {
    _ammoCount = 12;
    [ammoField setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _ammoCount]];
    fireButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Oh, and don't forget to call `reload` at some point early on to ensure _ammoCount and ammoField get initialised.

Comment: I tried this, and it takes the integer down to -1, then -2, etc. Here's what I'm doing: In the .h file: `code` NSInteger _ammoCount; `code` In the .m file: `code` - (IBAction)fire:(id)sender { _ammoCount--;
    [ammoDisplay setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _ammoCount]]; } `code` To clarify, the text box is initially 12, I want it to go to 11 on the first tap, then 10 for the second, etc, then stop at 0.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the code so "Fire" button is disabled if _ammoCount reaches 0.

Comment: I tried that, and it goes to 0 on the first tap. How would I get it to go to 11 first? Set _ammoCount to be equal to 12 (where would I declare that)?

Comment: Have you added `[self reload]` in the `viewDidLoad` method?

Answer (score 0):

Set Instance Integer

```
int x;
```

set value of it

```
x = 12;
```

do change in method

```
- (IBAction)fire {    
 [ammoField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",x]];
 x--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the value of count in viewdidload with an int variable

fire method decrease the count by 1

and reload method to return value to 12

log or use values accordingly

Answer (score -3):

Try this:-

```
  int i;
 -(void)ViewDidLoad 
{

  i=12;

}
 - (IBAction)fire 
{

  [ammoField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
  i--;
}

- (IBAction)reload {
i = 12;
[ammoField setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}
```

Hope it will work for you. Thanks :)